# Stacking images in Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I have two images `img1` and `img2` of shape `(20,20,3)`, that I have read using OpenCV.

I have applied the following statement on the two images:

```
np.stack([img1,img2], axis=2)
```

and got the following shape:

```
(20, 20, 2, 3)
```

Does that mean that we now have `2` `20x20x3` images? Are they (images and their channels) like put beside each other?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends how you define "beside"

Comment: @Eric I mean horizontally adjacent

Answer (score 2):

No you have created a new axis, your array now has four dimensions.

From the [Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html):

> numpy.stack(arrays, axis=0)
>
> Join a sequence of arrays along a **new** axis.

In order to get what you want try numpy.hstack:

```
a = np.zeros((20, 20, 3))

b = np.ones((20, 20, 3))

c = np.hstack((a, b))

print(c.shape)
```

> (20, 40, 3)